Get the distinct values from column X that are common to all values in column Y?
Let's say I have a table called Building_Rooms that has the following columns:

ID - Just a normal ID
Address - An nvarchar street address
RoomType - An nvarchar room type (e.g., bedroom, kitchen, bathroom, etc.)

(I know this looks like bad database design, but don't worry about that. I am trying to come up with the most bare-bones, easy-to-grasp illustrative example.)
How can I get the distinct RoomType values that exist for every Address value in the table?
For example, if the table contains both office buildings and residential buildings, the results would not have bedroom because most the office buildings don't have bedrooms, they would not have boardroom because most of the residences don't have boardrooms, and so on. We would probably expect the results to be nothing more than bathroom because that would be the only RoomType value that exists for every Address value on the table.
Reproducible example code:
create table [Building_RoomTypes]
(
    [ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [Address] varchar(255),
    [RoomType] varchar(255)
)

insert into [Building_RoomTypes]
values (NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'office'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'office'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'office'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'office'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'boardroom'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'kitchen'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'lobby'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'bathroom'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'bathroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'bedroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'bedroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'bedroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'kitchen'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'bathroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'living room'),
(NEWID(), '890 Downtown Avenue - Unit 1', 'bedroom'),
(NEWID(), '890 Downtown Avenue - Unit 1', 'kitchen'),
(NEWID(), '890 Downtown Avenue - Unit 1', 'bathroom')

Expected results if successfully querying for all distinct RoomType values that exist for all distinct Address values:
RoomType
--------
bathroom
kitchen

SQL Server version number: 14.0.2065.1

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Have you even tried anything???

Hmm... I have a solution, but it looks crazy inefficient. I'm not seeing a better option just now, but it know it has to be there.

Unless I'm missing something obvious, you just need a HAVING clause that uses COUNT(DISTINCT)
create table [Building_RoomTypes]
(
    [ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [Address] varchar(255),
    [RoomType] varchar(255)
)

insert into [Building_RoomTypes]
values (NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'office'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'office'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'office'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'office'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'boardroom'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'kitchen'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'lobby'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'bathroom'),
(NEWID(), '100 Wall Street', 'bathroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'bedroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'bedroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'bedroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'kitchen'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'bathroom'),
(NEWID(), '54 Residential Road', 'living room'),
(NEWID(), '890 Downtown Avenue - Unit 1', 'bedroom'),
(NEWID(), '890 Downtown Avenue - Unit 1', 'kitchen'),
(NEWID(), '890 Downtown Avenue - Unit 1', 'bathroom')
 

18 rows affected

SELECT
  RoomType
FROM
  Building_RoomTypes
GROUP BY
  RoomType
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT Address)
  =
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ADDRESS) FROM Building_RoomTypes)




RoomType




bathroom


kitchen



fiddle

I really don't love this, but I haven't found a better option yet.
with ranked as (
    select rt.roomtype, rank() over (order by count(address) desc) rk
    from (
         select distinct roomtype, address from building_roomtypes
    ) rt
    group by rt.roomtype
)
select roomtype
from ranked 
where rk = 1

It does at least work, on the assumption that at least one room type will meet the criteria. Otherwise, it will show the room type(s) that come closest.
See it here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/sIG88iml


If that assumption is not valid, you can do this:
select rt.roomtype
from (
     select distinct roomtype, address from building_roomtypes
) rt
group by rt.roomtype
having count(address) = (select count(distinct address) from building_roomtypes)

See it here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/Z_uQ_1tO

Again: I feel like there should be an way to do this that could perform MUCH better, but I'm not seeing it right now.
